# Is there a graph algorithm that satisfies the following conditions?

Tags: algorithm, graph

A graph of N nodes, where V = {0, 1, 2, ..., N}

All edges of this graph have a directional attribute, e.g. up, north, etc. and are thus directed. The graph is relatively sparse.

Vertices are arranged in three dimensions, and edges are all of equal length (i.e. moving left and then up is equivalent to moving up and then left, if both paths are possible) adjacent vertices may or may not have an edge.

Find a series of directional moves ending in node J, which ends at J for all vertices that are able to reach J

So, the question is:

What type of graph problem is this? How is this classified? I sincerely doubt this problem's uniqueness and I'm seeking to classify it before I slaughter it with a sick algorithm.

Thanks.

EDIT: An example would be 8 nodes arranged as the corners of a cube. Suppose along each edge of the cube there are two antiparallel graph edges (directional edges in both directions). Thus, if we say that J is in the 'lower' plane of the cube at the southwest corner, then moving down, west, south will reach J for any vertice that is able to reach J, including starting at J itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not perfectly sure I understand your problem, but why don't you use BFS starting from J and moving always in opposite direction than the edges imply? Any vertex from which J is reachable in (in terms of original directions) will be found, and you will get the series of moves (constructed in reversed order). What's more, the paths you will get will be the shortest paths (as all edges are equally weighted).

Time complexity is as low as possible: O(E) (you have to construct the graph anyway).

As to the classification you asked about: it's just a graph search problem.

Comment: Yes, it is a special graph, but the problem stated does not depend on that fact, neither does the solution. You cannot solve it faster than O(E), so there is no use of the fact it is a grid graph.

Comment: Actually, it's not that you want paths - you want one series of moves (e.g. left, right, up, left) that can reach J from every vertice that can reach J. Moves that are invalid for a given vertice (if a vertice only has left and up, and you try to move right) are consumed and ignored - they do not affect position.

Comment: So, this method does not directly solve the problem because each vertex that can reach J will have a unique path - the path that solves reaching J from any vertex will necessarily have 'dead' moves when executed from some vertices - moves that are part of the path (left, e.g.) but because there is no edge moving left from the vertex, they are ignored

Answer (score 0):

BFS can be used to reverse graph to all outgoing edge but if there are cycles in the graph then it will be troublesome to evaluate it so i think more cleaner way would be to evaluate the **Strongly Connected Components** in `O(E)` and then diminish the graph to node representing each SCC and then use BFS on the newer graph on node corresponding to J and reconstruct the path with the SCC of J separately.